# Given the Marginal Cost Function, Calculate Marginal Profit

Tags: calculus, economics

A friend of mine is having a bit of difficulty with their calculus homework and came to me for help, but I'm stumped at this point. The question is asking for the marginal profit of the 31st unit of a good, which I understand to be $P'(31)=R'(31)-C'(31)$, where $P'(x), R'(x),$ and $C'(x)$ are marginal profit, marginal revenue, and marginal cost, respectively.

The question gives that the price of a unit of the good as 215 dollars and gives the marginal cost function $C'(x)$. It also gives that there is a baseline manufacturing cost for any number of units of good, but my understanding is that this value is irrelevant to marginal profit. So the marginal profit of the 31st good would thus be $P'(31)=215-C'(31)$, yes? We've run the question several times but the online homework platform keeps marking it as wrong.

I suppose I should add that I've never encountered marginal profit before today, so I may just be misunderstanding something.

Comment: Looks good to me. Although the use of differential notation ($P'$ etc.) for quantities that depend on an integer number of units seems unusual -- so if something is wrong, it could be that you're misunderstanding their notation in that regard -- especially since you write that this is calculus homework and the discrete problem you describe doesn't involve any calculus -- but it's hard to say without seeing the original. For this sort of question that revolves around whether the error is in your work or in the problem, it always helps to present the problem as verbatim as you possibly can.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just used the notation out of habit, I haven't been in a class that used discrete values in a while and felt that verifying the concept was more important than the actual values in this case. We'll keep trying and notify the homework platform if nothing comes of it.

Comment: From the hint from @jorki, did you try $C(31)-C(30)$? That is a simplification of $P(31)-P(30)$ and is the marginal profit if output is discrete, (if say, you can't produce 30.01 cars).

Comment: Please provide all given information. What is $C'(x)$, for instance?

Comment: sorry, meant $C(30)-C(31)$, which is $215 -C(31)-[215 -C(30)]$.